# Why does a Asp.Net HTTP POST cause a 302 Redirect to GET even with EnableSessionState set to False

Tags: asp.net, http-post, session-state

I have a simple POST hit from a 3rd party website to a page on my ASP.Net website. Because the POST hit is not sending the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie it doesn't have the context for Session variables. To prevent the ASP.Net server from forcing a 302 Redirect to the same page with a GET method and a **?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1** appended to the URL I set the **EnableSessionState="False"** in the @Page tag. With the POST method working I'm able collect the variable values being posted and update a record in my local database.

This was working the other day exactly like it should, now today it is redirecting again and I can't grab the values in the variables accompany the POST. I don't get control in the page behind code until the GET request is serviced on the server. By then the needed POST variables are long gone.

```
<%@ Page AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="InvoiceUSAePay.aspx.cs"
Inherits="InvoiceUSAePay" Language="C#" EnableSessionState="False" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Invoice USAePay</title> 
    <meta content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1" name="GENERATOR" />
    <meta content="C#" name="CODE_LANGUAGE" />
    <meta content="JavaScript" name="vs_defaultClientScript" />
    <meta content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" name="vs_targetSchema" />
</head>
<body>
    Enable <%= state %>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is the post doing a redirect from the POST to GET when the EnableSessionState="False"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally stumbled onto what I had done wrong.

In the web.config file <system.web> property, I set **cookieless="AutoDetect"**. Yup, even when you set **EnableSessionState="False"** in a page's <%@ Page%> tag, the server is going to "AutoDetect" for a cookie. So the POST was coming in without a session cookie, so the server redirected the browser back to the server with a GET operation and a **?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1** parameter.

I've switched from AutoDetect to **UseCookies** and my pages have been working as expected, so far.

I felt it was important to document my solution for the next poor sole who has this problem. I'll likely be back here myself in the near future when I do it again.